# Layout-Parser Library to process a reading order of document in Python

Tags: python, parsing, optimization, layout, document

[layoutexample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ow2LA.jpg)
I want to modify the below code to index all types of columns/page layout in the reading order.

```
text = lp.Layout([b for b in layout if b.type=='Text' ])
figure = lp.Layout([b for b in layout if b.type=='Figure'])

text = lp.Layout([b for b in text \
if not any(b.is_in(b_fig) for b_fig in figure)])

h, w = image.shape[:2]
left_interval = lp.Interval(0, w/2*1.05, axis='x').put_on_canvas(image)

lp.Interval(start, end, axis='x', canvas_height=0, canvas_width=0) ##

left = text.filter_by(left_interval, center=True)
left.sort(key = lambda b:b.coordinates[1])

right = [b for b in text if b not in left]
right.sort(key = lambda b:b.coordinates[1])

text = lp.Layout([b.set(id = idx) for idx, b in enumerate(left + right)])
```

Reference-  https://layout-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: You need to include more detail about your problem, including what you've tried, a minimum piece of code to show what you're trying to do. Consider the audience is not familiar with the layout-parser library - you will need to provide more context so that people can help you

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with this, it will not detect the tables with columns, you can try other part given in the layout parser WITH Google Clod Computer vision.

[Read on this link](https://layout-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/parse_ocr/index.html#)